# Nodejs upload multiple images - create dir when doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Im using nodejs and multer to upload multiple images.
Firsat check is if dir exist. If not will be created.

**Error**: When folder doesnt exist all images are passing the first condition  fs.access by giving the message "Directory doesnt exist" but then dir is created so the second image gets an error "Directory exist".

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const userId = encryptFolder(req.params["id"]);
    const dtrToCreate = "C:/Users/User/Pictures/" + userId;
    fs.access(dtrToCreate, (error) => {
      if (error) {
       console.log("Directory does not exist.", userId);
        fs.mkdirSync(dtrToCreate, (error, data) => {
          if (error) {
            throw error;
          }
        cb(null, "C:/Users/User/Pictures/"); 
        });

      } else {
        console.log("Directory exists.", userId);
        cb(null, "C:/Users/User/Pictures/");
      }
    });
  },
```

When directory exist images are uploaded sucessfully.

Comment: It seems wrong that you append `userId` to `dtrToCreate` but not to `cb(null, ...)`. Are you sure you need to handle that yourself at all? "You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you." https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage

Comment: @some-user they want to create per-user directories so you can't just pass in a string as destination.

Comment: Have you tried using a mutex to avoid race conditions? Or creating the directory in an earlier handler?

Comment: Or using `fs.existsSync` instead of `fs.access`?

Comment: ..yet the files get saved in `Pictures` in every case.. why is it a problem if the directory exists.. it's unclear what you're trying to achieve here..

Comment: Im creating a folder on the path  dtrToCreate+userId that ususlly will be something like  C:/Users/User/Pictures/folder1

fs.existsSync dont work at all.

Files getting saved when folder is created. When folder is not only 1 image will be saved since the next one will be catched on error Directory exist

Comment: @traynor im trying to put files into a direcotry. If the direcotry doesnt exist should be created firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

Since there are multiple files should be a recusrsive function to check if folder exist each time files passing.

```js
  fs.mkdirSync(dtrToCreate, { recursive: true })
        return cb(null, dtrToCreate)
```